# React route doesn't render component based on Django REST url

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a password reset mechanism implemented in my React app via Django Rest API endpoint.
Now the Api sends an e-mail with a link in that structure:

> http://localhost:3000/api/user/auth/password-reset/confirm/MQ/b3x446-bd2f340d3a6de198925002c92e361d8d

In my component I have the following route

```
<Routes>
    <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} /> // works
    <Route exact path="/reset-password" element={<ResetPassword />} /> // works
    <Route path="/api/user/auth/password-reset/confirm/*" 
    element={<ResetPasswordConfirm />} /> // doesn't work
</Routes>
```

Somehow the `password-reset/..` route doesn't work, the others do though.

Answer (score 0):

you can add as `:id` for dynamic path

```
<Route path="/api/user/auth/password-reset/confirm/:mq/:id" 
    element={<ResetPasswordConfirm />} />
```

Comment: doesnt seem to render the component either :-(

Comment: @Jonas Could the server be handle the /api/ requests?

Comment: yes it returns the correct url, but the url isn't rendered by React

Comment: if  server handle /api/ reuqest, react-router cannot catch the url. should use re-redirect  to client from server

Comment: hm the url is provided in an e-mail, when I click it React doesnt render the component